# Grabbing data from multiple form fields and creating a JSON String dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I would like to create a JSON string using multiple input fiels with same cla. Allow me to show you my HTML for explanation

```
<div>
    Email:<input title="QA" type="text" class="email">
    Name: <input type="text" class="name">
</div>

<div>
    Email:<input title="DEV" type="text" class="email">
    Name: <input type="text" class="name">
</div>

<div>
    Email:<input title="PROD" type="text" class="email">
    Name: <input type="text" class="name">
</div>
```

Currently my JavaScript is as follows:

```
 var ServerUser = [];

 $("input[class=email]").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("title");
    var email = $(this).val();

    tmp = {};
    tmp['id '] = id;
    tmp['email '] = email;

    ServerUser.push(tmp);
 });
```

However what it produces the following result

```
[{title: QA, email: 'a@a.com'}, {title: PROD, email: 'b@b.com'},{title: DEV, email: 'c@c.com'}]
```

What I WOULD like to do is as follows

```
[{title: QA, email: 'a@a.com', name: 'Paul'}, {title: PROD, email: 'b@b.com', name: 'Mark'},{title: DEV, email: 'c@c.com', name: 'Mike'}]
```

Where the name value would come from the respective Name input field.

How do I approach this problem? Thank you for your help and reading this.

Regards.

Comment: how can that code possibly create json with the keys `title` and `email` when you are clearly using `TaskID` and `ClientEmail` in your js? I assume you simplified it a little. You'll need to get the `name` inside of the same each that is getting the `email` and `title`.

Comment: @KevinB oops, my mistake. Fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var inputs = $('input.email'), tmp;
$.each(inputs, function(i, obj) {
  tmp = {
    'title': $(obj).attr('title'),
    'email': $(obj).val(),
    'name' : $(obj).siblings('.name').val()
  };

  ServerUser.push(tmp);
});
```

That should do it

Comment: works perfect! Thank you. You do have a slight typo on your code snippet at 'email': $(ob).val(), should be 'obj' for it to run perfectly :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Why you just don't do it manually by inserting variables into prewrited string?

Rename the inputs by each's title.

Example:

var onejson = "[{title: **QA**, email: **emailQA**, name: **nameQA**}, {title: **DEV**, email: **emailDEV**, name: **nameDEV**}, {title: **PRO**, email: **emailPRO**, name: **namePRO**}];

I know it's a little steparound, but I think it's not bad solution and I would do it like I've described. Hope helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor programming practice, because your input fields should have decipherable unique identifiers you can use to get their values, but for your example using the [Next Sibling Selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) will allow you to select the next input element in your div's.

example:

```
 var ServerUser = [];
    $("input[class=email]").each(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("title");
    var email = $(this).val();
    var name = $(this).parent().first().find('input:last').val();

    tmp = {};
    tmp['TaskID'] = id;
    tmp['ClientEmail'] = email;
    tmp['ClientName'] = name;

    ServerUser.push(tmp);
 });
```

This is a long selector, and there's probably a better way to structure your form so you don't need to do this, but for as long as the name input is the last one you're going to have, this will work.